Loading several pictures in TASM 8086
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
p386
DATASEG
filename1 db 'picture1.bmp',0
filename2 db 'instructions.bmp',0
filehandle1 dw ?
filehandle2 dw ?
Header1 db 54 dup (0)
Header2 db 54 dup (0)
Palette1 db 256*4 dup (0)
Palette2 db 256*4 dup (0)
ScrLine1 db 320 dup (0)
ScrLine2 db 320 dup (0)
ErrorMsg1 db 'Error', 13, 10 ,'$'
ErrorMsg2 db 'Error', 13, 10 ,'$'




CODESEG
; The following procedures are picture related
;-------------------------------------------------------------------
;Prints the bmp file provided
;IN: ax - img offset, imgHeight (dw), imgWidth (dw), printAdd (dw)
;OUT: printed bmp file
proc OpenFile1
; Open file
mov ah, 3Dh
xor al, al
mov dx, offset filename1
int 21h
jc openerror1
mov [filehandle1], ax
ret
openerror1 :
mov dx, offset ErrorMsg1
mov ah, 9h
int 21h
ret
endp OpenFile1
proc ReadHeader1
; Read BMP file header, 54 bytes
mov ah,3fh
mov bx, [filehandle1]
mov cx,54
mov dx,offset Header1
int 21h
ret
endp ReadHeader1
proc ReadPalette1
; Read BMP file color palette, 256 colors * 4 bytes (400h)
mov ah,3fh
mov cx,400h
mov dx,offset Palette1
int 21h
ret
endp ReadPalette1
proc CopyPal1
; Copy the colors palette to the video memory
; The number of the first color should be sent to port 3C8h
; The palette is sent to port 3C9h
mov si,offset Palette1
mov cx,256
mov dx,3C8h
mov al,0
; Copy starting color to port 3C8h
out dx,al
; Copy palette itself to port 3C9h
inc dx
PalLoop1:
; Note: Colors in a BMP file are saved as BGR values rather than RGB .
mov al,[si+2] ; Get red value .
shr al,2 ; Max. is 255, but video palette maximal
; value is 63. Therefore dividing by 4.
out dx,al ; Send it .
mov al,[si+1] ; Get green value .
shr al,2
out dx,al ; Send it .
mov al,[si] ; Get blue value .
shr al,2
out dx,al ; Send it .
add si,4 ; Point to next color .
; (There is a null chr. after every color.)
loop PalLoop1
ret
endp CopyPal1
proc CopyBitmap1
; BMP graphics are saved upside-down .
; Read the graphic line by line (200 lines in VGA format),
; displaying the lines from bottom to top.
mov ax, 0A000h
mov es, ax
mov cx,200
PrintBMPLoop1 :
push cx
; di = cx*320, point to the correct screen line
mov di,cx
shl cx,6
shl di,8
add di,cx
; Read one line
mov ah,3fh
mov cx,320
mov dx,offset ScrLine1
int 21h
; Copy one line into video memory
cld ; Clear direction flag, for movsb
mov cx,320
mov si,offset ScrLine1
rep movsb ; Copy line to the screen
 ;rep movsb is same as the following code :
 ;mov es:di, ds:si
 ;inc si
 ;inc di
 ;dec cx
;loop until cx=0
pop cx
loop PrintBMPLoop1
ret
endp CopyBitmap1
proc CloseFile1
mov ah,3Eh
mov bx,[filehandle1]
int 21h
ret
endp CloseFile1



proc OpenFile2
; Open file
pusha
mov ah, 3Dh
xor al, al
mov dx, offset filename2
int 21h
jc openerror2
mov [filehandle2], ax
popa
ret
openerror2 :
mov dx, offset ErrorMsg2
mov ah, 9h
int 21h
popa
ret
endp OpenFile2
proc ReadHeader2
; Read BMP file header, 54 bytes
mov ah,3fh
mov bx, [filehandle2]
mov cx,54
mov dx,offset Header2
int 21h
ret
endp ReadHeader2
proc ReadPalette2
; Read BMP file color palette, 256 colors * 4 bytes (400h)
mov ah,3fh
mov cx,400h
mov dx,offset Palette2
int 21h
ret
endp ReadPalette2
proc CopyPal2
; Copy the colors palette to the video memory
; The number of the first color should be sent to port 3C8h
; The palette is sent to port 3C9h
mov si,offset Palette2
mov cx,256
mov dx,3C8h
mov al,0
; Copy starting color to port 3C8h
out dx,al
; Copy palette itself to port 3C9h
inc dx
PalLoop2:
; Note: Colors in a BMP file are saved as BGR values rather than RGB .
mov al,[si+2] ; Get red value .
shr al,2 ; Max. is 255, but video palette maximal
; value is 63. Therefore dividing by 4.
out dx,al ; Send it .
mov al,[si+1] ; Get green value .
shr al,2
out dx,al ; Send it .
mov al,[si] ; Get blue value .
shr al,2
out dx,al ; Send it .
add si,4 ; Point to next color .
; (There is a null chr. after every color.)
loop PalLoop2
ret
endp CopyPal2
proc CopyBitmap2
; BMP graphics are saved upside-down .
; Read the graphic line by line (200 lines in VGA format),
; displaying the lines from bottom to top.
mov ax, 0A000h
mov es, ax
mov cx,200
PrintBMPLoop2 :
push cx
; di = cx*320, point to the correct screen line
mov di,cx
shl cx,6
shl di,8
add di,cx
; Read one line
mov ah,3fh
mov cx,320
mov dx,offset ScrLine2
int 21h
; Copy one line into video memory
cld ; Clear direction flag, for movsb
mov cx,320
mov si,offset ScrLine2
rep movsb ; Copy line to the screen
 ;rep movsb is same as the following code :
 ;mov es:di, ds:si
 ;inc si
 ;inc di
 ;dec cx
;loop until cx=0
pop cx
loop PrintBMPLoop2
ret
endp CopyBitmap2



;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
start:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    ; Graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
    ; Process BMP file
    call OpenFile1
    call ReadHeader1
    call ReadPalette1
    call CopyPal1
    call CopyBitmap1
    ; Wait for key press
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    cmp al , 'i'
    call CloseFile1
    je function_call
    
    ; Back to text mode
    ;mov ah, 0
    ;mov al, 2
    ;int 10h
    jmp continue
    function_call:
    call OpenFile2
    ; Graphic mode
    ; Process BMP file
    call ReadHeader2
    call ReadPalette2
    call CopyPal2
    call CopyBitmap2
    ; Wait for key press
    continue:
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    cmp al, 'b'
    je OpenFile1
    ; Back to text mode
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h
    

‏exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start

I have been writing some functions in TASM 8086 for a while, and now I want to print an image to the screen after the user enters a specific letter. For some reason after I enter the letter, the program instead of printing the image just writes error. I tried to Turbo Debug my code and I saw that the right value enters to al, and it enters the functions of the second image but there it gets wrong somehow.
While I debugged my code I saw that in the openFile1 function the line jc openerror1 changes to jb #nameofthefile#openerror
Can someone help me?
I tried looking for explanations on the internet and YouTube, understand the line jc openerror1 and why it changed in the debugger.

jb is the same instruction as jc. It's just a different mnemonic which is more readable in certain situations. Check why the carry flag is set.

Your second file is instructions.bmp which is not in 8.3 format. Rename it or use the short name.


i want to print an image to the screen after the user enters a specific letter. For some reason after I enter the letter, the program instead of printing the image just writes error.

There are a number of errors in the program:

In order to request displaying the second bitmap, you have code like:
cmp al , 'i'
call CloseFile1
je function_call

That call to CloseFile1 is out of place. It could potentially destroy the very flag that the je instruction is trying to act upon. Move this instruction to just below call CopyBitmap1:
call CopyBitmap1
call CloseFile1


The filename for the second bitmap is not a valid 8.3 filename. DOS might truncate instructions.bmp to instruct.bmp, so make sure that file exists. But better still, why don't you name this file picture2.bmp. Don't you find "instructions" an odd name for a bitmap?

When processing the request to display the first file again, you have code like:
cmp al, 'b'
je OpenFile1

This is wrong because you are jumping to the start of a proc, and as you certainly know, a proc is code that you are supposed to call. The ret instruction that ends that proc has nowhere to go since je did not put a return address on the stack.


start:
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax
  ; Graphic mode
  mov  ax, 0013h
  int  10h
BMP1:
  call OpenFile1     ;
  call ReadHeader1   ;;
  call ReadPalette1  ;;; Why not write all of this in a single proc?
  call CopyPal1      ;;;
  call CopyBitmap1   ;;
  call CloseFile1    ;
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  cmp  al , 'i'
  jne  CONT
BMP2:
  call OpenFile2     ;
  call ReadHeader2   ;;
  call ReadPalette2  ;;; Why not write all of this in a single proc?
  call CopyPal2      ;;;
  call CopyBitmap2   ;;
  call CloseFile2    ;        <<< You forgot this one completely!
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
CONT:
  cmp  al, 'b'
  je   BMP1
  ; Back to text mode
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  10h
‏exit:


I found more errors still, but let's not turn this into a code review.
eg. When your OpenFile proc detects an error, it prints an error message to the screen, but then the program happily continues with no valid file handle available. That's a recipe for disaster!
